# share audio on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Don't share mp3 audio in my app (in raw/suono.mp3) on  whatapp app

```
    final Button pulsante2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.pulsante2);
    pulsante2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            suono2=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.suono2);
            suono2.start();

        }
        });
     //tasto premuto piu a lungo
    pulsante2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/*");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/raw/" + R.raw.suono2);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));


            return true;


        }
        });
```

*what app say me can't load file please reload*

Comment: Few apps handle `android.resource` schemes. Copy the audio content to a file, then use `FileProvider` to make it available via a `Uri`.

Comment: how add in file provider? need code

Comment: [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that uses `FileProvider` to serve a PDF file that originally came from assets. You would switch the code to serve your audio content that originally came from a raw resource.

Comment: don t understand :(

Answer (score 0):

```
              InputStream inputStream;
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
                try {
                    inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.suono2);
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: try this but when send to what app it's say condivision fail pls reload